# shared_ptr from abstract class

Tags: c++, shared-ptr, mediator

I have this mediator pattern:

File `actor.hpp`

```
#pragma once
#include <memory>
#include "mediator.hpp"

class actor : std::shared_from_this<actor>
{
  public:

  actor(std::shared_ptr<mediator> mediator) : mediator_(mediator)
  {
  }

  virtual ~actor() = 0;

  virtual void changed()
  {
    mediator_->actor_changed(std::make_shared<actor>(this));
  }

  private:

  std::shared_ptr<mediator> mediator_;
};
```

File `mediator.hpp`

```
#pragma once
#include <memory>

class actor;

class mediator : public std::shared_from_this<mediator>
{
  public:

  virtual ~mediator() = 0;

  virtual void actor_changed(std::shared_ptr<actor> actor) = 0;
}
```

An implementation of an actor `request_handler.hpp`

```
#pragma once
#include "actor.hpp"

class request_handler : public actor
{
  public:

  request_handler(std::shared_ptr<mediator> mediator) : actor(mediator)
  {
  }

  void handle_request()
  {
    changed();
  }
};
```

But I get the error message

```
actor.hpp:16 error: invalid new-expression of abstract class type 'actor'
```

because I cannot instatiate an abstract class. But what would be the correct way of doing this?

Comment: shared_from_this; but unless your callers are going to keep a reference to it; you're digging a hole for yourself, and you'd be better off just passing a pointer

Comment: You should not do `std::make_shared<actor>(this)`, instead use the `shared_from_this` member function.

Answer (score 4):

This code:

```
 mediator_->actor_changed(std::make_shared<actor>(this));
```

is logically equal to:

```
auto ptr = std::shared_ptr<actor>( new actor( this ) );
mediator_->actor_changed(ptr);
```

and this is most probably not what you want, so you need to call [shared_from_this()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/enable_shared_from_this/shared_from_this) instead:

```
mediator_->actor_changed( this->shared_from_this() );
```

and class you need to inherit from is called [std::enable_shared_from_this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/enable_shared_from_this) not `shared_from_this`